# jQuery change CSS after a certain amount of time

Tags: jquery, css, time, click, intervals

I have a navigation that, when one of it's nav items is clicked, will use jQuery to change it's z-index to 0. Then, after 2 seconds, I would like the z-index to be changed to 2.

I tried using delay() but apparently that doesn't work when changing the CSS.

Comment: Do you just want the element to disappear and then after 2 seconds, reappear? There's better ways to make things disappear and reappear. like jQuery.show()/.hide()

Comment: Nope, I just wanted to change the z-index because it causes the links to be unclickable, but still visible, for 2 seconds

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a setTimeout like this

```
$(elem).css('z-index','0');
setTimeout(function(){ $(elem).css('z-index','2'); },2000)
```

Answer (score 2):

In javascript you can use either setTimeout or setInterval to accomplish that

```
setTimeout("javascript statement",milliseconds);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp