# How do I set css using jQuery .css after a period of time?

Tags: jquery, css, time

I couldn't figure out How to set time on jQuery .css property

I found one answer which is the closest to my question in
[jQuery change CSS after a certain amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411644/jquery-change-css-after-a-certain-amount-of-time)

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#homebutton,#title").click(function(){
            $("#title").css("font-size", "100%");  
            setTimeout(function(){ $("#title").css("font-size", "100%"); },2000)
        });
    });
</script>
```

I don't know what is wrong with that. 

It seems like the solution I mentioned above doesn't work for me.


Thank you in advance guys

-----------------------------------------EDIT----------------------------------------------

Thanks for the response folks, there are several things that I want to re-explain:

1. I initially set the font-size to 150% in my CSS, which mean through my jQuery, I expected it to change the font-size into 100%.
2. I think I've misinterpreted the code, what I wanted to set is the time for decreasing gradually and **not** the timer

Basically, I want to change the font-size using jquery with transition, and not a sudden change

Comment: You set the font size to 100% in that code and then set it to 100% again 2 seconds later. Why?

Comment: You're setting the font-size immediately, then again in 2 seconds. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Your code is valid, please explain what you want to do in more detail, please note you are setting the font size at the same size twice!

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding folks, I forgot to mentioned that I set the font-size value to 150% initially in my CSS                        ......................................................................I've re-explained my problems to the responses below, hope it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trouble is you first set `font-size: 100%` immediately, then you set it to the *same value* again after 2 seconds.  Ie, you aren't changing the css.

To set the css value when clicked, and then set it to something else 2 seconds later, use different values in each call to `.css()`.  Eg, to decrease the font size by half initially, then bring it back to normal size 2 seconds later:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#homebutton,#title").click(function(){
        $("#title").css("font-size", "50%");
        setTimeout(function(){ $("#title").css("font-size", "100%"); },2000);
    });
});
```

**Edit:** To gradually decrease the font size, you want to use `.animate()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#homebutton,#title").click(function(){
        $("#title").animate({ "font-size": "50%" }, 2000);
    });
});
```

**Demo:** [jsfiddle.net/Y6CrG/](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6CrG/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm kind of newbie here , I'm sorry I think my question wasn't clear. I've re-explained again on the post below.

Comment: @EdwinLimantara - I've updated my answer with details on how to gradually decrease the font size and included a demo link.

Answer (score 0):

Change the font-size after the 2 second timeout. For example:

```
$("#title").click(function(){
  $("#title").css("font-size", "100%");  
  setTimeout(function(){ $("#title").css("font-size", "80%"); },2000)                               
});
```

I tried it in the following jsfiddle and it worked fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/kianoshp/z9QeY/

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding here, let me try to explain: 1. I initially set the font-size: 150% in my css file, which mean that I wanted to change the font-size into 100% from the previous value  ......................................................................2.What I meant to say is, not to change the font size for 2 second, but I meant I need a transition(the font decrease gradually), ................................................................. for example: $("#homebutton").animate({
     top: '20px',
           left:'60px'},1500);

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this:**

```
  $('#title').animate({fontSize : '100%'});
```

**And If you want to set the duration You can use these**

```
  $('#title').animate({fontSize : '100%'}, "slow");
  $('#title').animate({fontSize : '100%'}, "fast");
```